# VSTO: how write into "Recent Documents" of MS-Office

Tags: .net, vsto

I'm working with VSTO (using VS2019) to handle customized encrypted documents to be created from within MS-Office 365 (local, not Online).

The problem is that saved documents are using also a custom extension (necessary for further processing by other applications) and, obviously, the MS-Office apps do not recognize them for adding  into "Recent Documents" listing.

is there any way to make my VSTO adding the documents (and their locations) into that MS-Office listing?

I appreciate any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Office applications keep the recent files list in the Windows registry. Read more about that in the [Edit the Windows registry to clear the list of most recently used files in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/settings/clear-most-recently-used-file) article.

- Word

Go to the following Registry `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Word\FileMRU`, check the value entry for the list available on the right hand side under File MRU

- Excel

Go to the following Registry  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Excel\FileMRU`, check the value entry for the list available on the right hand side under File MRU

where the `XX.0` string in the windows registry path stands for the Office version installed on the machine.